# Javascript Math.floor function blunder or implementation mystery?

Tags: javascript

```
    ​document.writeln(Math.floor(43.9));
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​produces 43 in the browser.

```
​document.writeln(Math.floor(43.9999));​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

produces 43

```
 ​document.writeln(Math.floor(43.999999999999));​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

again 43

However,

```
    document.writeln(Math.floor(43.99999999999999));
```

produces 44.

The magic number of 9's after the decimal point seems to be 15*.

Why is this?

Furthermore, Does the Math.floor function accept the number as a number object, or a number value?

Comment: You know about `0.1 + 0.2 !== 0.3`, right? `:)` Your observation is probably a variation on the theme.

Comment: Yes, but I also know that in some specific mathmatical and physics contexts, especially with limits, .9999999999999999823482361231 != 1

Comment: I assume (not sure) that the function expects a float and in the first number which returns 44 (the one with 14 9's) exceeds the float size, so your constant number is being rounded and then passed to the function. Again, just a guess!

Comment: Btw, the magic number is 15 in my Firebug console

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - 15 in chrome as well: http://jsfiddle.net/k7huV/1/

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I was using Jsfiddle, so not sure how all that happens, but I will go by Chrome and Firebug. Thanks, I'll edit that.

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/k7huV/2/ , you can see that 43.99 (15 9s) is actually **stored** as 44. So this is not a rounding issue in the math algorithm but instead in the way the number is stored.

Comment: @TravisJ so then, is this not specifically a Javascript issue then, but rather an implementation issue?

Comment: @treehau5 i think 15 9s is plenty for whatever you are trying to do

Comment: @treehau5 It is a consequence of the way numbers are stored. Since there is not infinite memory, not every number can be stored exactly

Comment: @treehau5 The JavaScript language uses the double-precision 64-bit format IEEE 754 as its *Number* type. Your observation is related to that format, not JavaScript itself.

Comment: @treehau5 - Although ugly, there is a way to get around this using strings. Not pretty, but it can work if you can manage to store your numbers in strings. See below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point format (which is what JavaScript uses for its *Number* type) gives you a precision of 15 - 17 significant decimal digits.

> This gives from 15 - 17 significant decimal digits precision. If a
>   decimal string with at most 15 significant decimal is converted to
>   IEEE 754 double precision and then converted back to the same number
>   of significant decimal, then the final string should match the
>   original; and if an IEEE 754 double precision is converted to a
>   decimal string with at least 17 significant decimal and then converted
>   back to double, then the final number must match the original [1].

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64

Answer (score 5):

[Double-precision floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) (a.k.a. doubles) are capable of storing a very wide range of values but only with limited precision—15–17 significant digits. If you do the following, you'll see what happens:

```
var x = 43.99999999999999;
var y = 43.999999999999999;

document.writeln(x); // 43.99999999999999
document.writeln(y); // 44
document.writeln(Math.floor(x)); // 43
document.writeln(Math.floor(y)); // 44
```

You'll see the same in other languages as well. For example, PHP:

```
echo floor(43.99999999999999); // 43
echo floor(43.999999999999999); // 44
```

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome, if I just type `43.99999999999999999999999` into the console, it outputs `44`, that's probably what you're running into. Floating points are approximations

Answer (score 1):

See this workaround:

http://jsfiddle.net/k7huV/3/

```
var x = 43;
for( var i = 0; i < 16; i++ ){
    if( i == 0 ) x += ".";
    x += "9";   
}
document.writeln(x);
document.writeln(parseInt(x));
```

Output: `43.9999999999999999 43`

Correctly floors 43.999999999999999 to 43.

Answer (score 1):

You may pass both an instance of Number, as well as a number literal.

```
Math.floor(43.99999999999999);

Math.floor(new Number(43.99999999999999));
```